# How to compare two lists and return the number of times they match at each index in python?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists containing 1's and 0's, e.g.

```
list1 = [1,1,0,1,0,1]
list2 = [0,1,0,1,1,0]
```

I want to find the number of times they match at each index. So in this case the output would be 3 because they have the same value at indices 1,2 and 3 only.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
matches_list = []
for i in list1:
   index = list[1].index(i)
   if list1[index] == list2[index]:
            mathes_list.append(i)
   else:
       pass
return len(matches_list)
```

However this is very slow and I want to do this many times over to compare a large number of these lists

I was hoping someone could advise me on a quicker way to do this. Is there a way to use the set() function, or something similar, for example to compare two lists but maintain the order of each one?

Comment: Use could use `enumerate` for the first loop. Then you don't have to get the index again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`zip` the lists, compare the elements, compute the sum.

```
>>> list1 = [1,1,0,1,0,1]
>>> list2 = [0,1,0,1,1,0]
>>> sum(a == b for a,b in zip(list1, list2))
3
```

(Consider using `itertools.izip` in Python 2 for memory efficiency.)

Comment: Thanks, will this still work if the lists are different lengths? i.e. will it just count to the end of the shortest of the two lists?

Comment: @BenJeffrey `zip` and `itertools.izip` will truncate the longer of the two lists. If you want to take into account lists of different lengths, use `itertools.izip_longest`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a lightning fast [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) answer:

```
import numpy as np
list1 = np.array([1,1,0,1,0,1])
list2 = np.array([0,1,0,1,1,0])

len(np.where(list1==list2)[0])
```

The numpy `np.where` function will return the indexes of all the points in the pair of lists that conform to a function (in this case list1==list2 at indices [1,2,3]) along with a datatype description. In the above case, I strip out the array of indices and count how many there are with `len()`.

Comment: Using numpy on small lists isn't exactly "lightning fast". The conversion to numpy arrays and the function call overhead makes this approach (using the lists in the OP) 3-5 times slower than any pure-python approach. It will scale better but numpy is typically only faster if the input is already an array and these arrays contain several hundred items.

Comment: Fair point - I was making the assumption that the OP was intending to scale up to longer and larger lists of numbers. Though interestingly, they mention running it across a large number of lists which might require a slightly different approach again.

Comment: Why not `np.sum(list1 == list2)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` with `operator.eq` and `sum`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> sum(map(operator.eq, list1, list2))
```

This works because `True` is interpreted as 1 when summed and `False` like `0`.

---

You could also use `numpy` for this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.count_nonzero(np.asarray(list1) == np.asarray(list2))
```